# Procedure or function sp_select_companydetails has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am really get depressed about this error all function code is correct but still its giving me the error, I am trying to select information from SQL Server database.

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure sp_select_companydetails
    @id varchar(5)
as
begin
    select company_name, company_address 
    from CompanyDetails
end
```

C# Code:

2) On Form button click event

```
string id = "1";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_select_companydetails";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
FillDataset();
```

In class

```
public DataSet FillDataset()
{
    try
    {
        using (cmd)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            return ds;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

When I click on form button I get this error:

> Procedure or function sp_select_companydetails has too many arguments specified.

Suggest me good solution

Thank you in advance

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a global SqlCommand, create it as new everytime you need it. This is a recommended approach when you deal with disposable objects

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_select_companydetails", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

By the way, we cannot see how do you create the SqlConnection, but it seems that you have another disposable object kept at the global level. This is particular nasty with an SqlConnection because this object keeps references to system wide resources both on client and on server. Do not create global connection objects, just create a global method that returns the current connectionstring to use in creation of the local SqlConnection (the `GetConnectionString()` in my example above). If you think that this is a performance killer I suggest you to read about [the concept of connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you sir, yes you are right i am not going to use global sqlcommand, can you please suggest better option :)

Comment: As shown in the SqlCommand you use a local variable also for the SqlConnection.